# want to create an audio playlist dynamically by using ".plist" file an then want to play it in iphone in built audio player

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to create an audio playlist dynamically by using ".plist" file an then want to play it in iphone in built audio player. But during creation of audio list in plist there is no option in "type" to select data type for audio file. 
Plz guide any one what approach I should follow ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly. Can you specify what APIs you are using and what you are trying to do with more detail?

As far as Property Lists go, they are very generic so there wouldn't be anything for audio files in particular. You could specify the data type as a string.

**How to approach this**: First of all, you need to read the list into an NSArray and use that to generate a table view with your track listing (use tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath: to start playing a track upon the user selecting it). To play a track use AVAudioPlayer.

Comment: Actually I just want to display a song list in view and on selection they should be play in iphone audio player. Same as we use in our mobile phones to play song list.

Comment: Plz guide me wat should I do to display a song list in plist and use this plist in code so that on selection it should play in audio player.

Comment: I have added a general approach to how you can do this. For more details on the actual code, check the docs.